# Is there any configuration for the windows to always open centered in WindowMaker?

Tags: window-manager

Is there any way to make WindowMaker open the windows always centered?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com).

> DisplayFusion will make your
>   multi-monitor life much easier. With
>   powerful features like Multi-Monitor
>   Taskbars, TitleBar Buttons and fully
>   customizable HotKeys, DisplayFusion
>   will make managing your multiple
>   monitors easy. Take a look at some of
>   the features below to learn how
>   DisplayFusion can help you!

Here's a little .gif that shows some of the features

[image]

Comment: It's just for Microsoft Windows, I need something from WMaker itself, or with source to compile for my embedded Unix..